# What are Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

As per standard Array definition: An array is a variable which allows you to store multiple value of same Data Type.

In PHP, say `$a=array("abc",123,"4");`

What will be $a[0] `abc` , $a[1] `123` and $a[2] `4` treated as String, Numeric value or character value and Why?

Comment: `var_dump($a)`... or if you are refering to the internals: http://lxr.php.net

Comment: What “standard array definition” are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in PHP are different, there's only one type of array which an store different types. in Your example the items keep their original type. abc is a String, 123 is a number and 4 is a string.

You can even have nonnumeric keys. For Example `$a["a"] = "test"`.

Answer (score 2):

In php arrays are not arrays.

If you really want to know how this whole thing works, i would recommend for you to watch this presentations: [PHP UK Conference 2012 - PHP under the hood, by Johannes Schlüter](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxxIXPc9IR8).

Also, as @RepWhoringPeeHaa mentioned : use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

Answer (score 1):

PHP treats array differently from general `definition` of them.

I suggest you read more about them on the [official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa: valid criticisms of W3Schools aside, aren't third-party edits meant to avoid changing the substantial meaning of a contribution? hjpotter92 is welcome to recommend whoever he/she likes, imo.

Comment: @halfer See me as a quality assurance. I like to make SO a better place with good information. Not only for OP, but also for other people in the future. Think about the children ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Arrays

An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

**Specifying with array()**

An array can be created using the array() language construct. It takes any number of comma-separated key => value pairs as arguments.

```
array(
    key  => value,
    key2 => value2,
    key3 => value3,
    ...
)
```

The comma after the last array element is optional and can be omitted. This is usually done for single-line arrays, i.e. array(1, 2) is preferred over array(1, 2, ). For multi-line arrays on the other hand the trailing comma is commonly used, as it allows easier addition of new elements at the end.

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);

// as of PHP 5.4
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
?>
```